# Registration problem

Tags: 8, forms, users

I was testing my users accounts on my site, and login works fine for my admin account I created with MySQL in terminal.

But when I try to create a new account with the registration form I have, it shows the succeed message I created:

> Thank you for registering

Still the succeed message is shown, the account isn't created and an error occurs:

> Unable to send email. Contact the site administrator if the problem
>   persists.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unable to send email. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists.**

This error is due to email sending failed.

You can use [SMTP Authentication Support](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) module for sending email.

> This module allows Drupal to bypass the PHP mail() function and send
>   email directly to an SMTP server. The module supports SMTP
>   authentication and can even connect to servers using SSL if supported
>   by PHP.

You can take the picture as reference for SMTP configuration.

[image]

Comment: Still the same problem, the information about the module is a bit unclear.
I need to do something else beyond install and enable the module?

Comment: Have you enabled and configure this module and try?

Comment: /admin/config/system/smtp
in this page I already turned it on, but I don't know what to put in "SMTP server" and may be the rest of the configuration.
"Smtp.gmail.com" do the trick?

Comment: You can take the picture as reference for SMTP configuration.

Comment: Now the same error happens after I save configurations.
When I go check the log messages, it shows the error:
"Error sending e-mail from *** to ***: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate."

Comment: you are putting your gmail id and password properly. you can also see the error "/admin/reports/dblog".

Comment: I already checked several times and my id and password and correct.
I didn't understood what you mean by "you can also see the error "/admin/reports/dblog".". I already posted on my previous comment what was the error "Error sending e-mail from *** to ***: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate."

Comment: are you using gmail id or other ? If gmail then Less secure apps turn on. https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: No, I'm not using gmail account to send emails, I'm using company's email. And activated access for less secure apps but the same error still persists :/
EDIT: Now I tried to put my personal gmail account and it worked:O

Comment: Then you need to check your smtp server first.http://www.serversmtp.com/en/what-is-my-smtp

Comment: How do I know which one is my smtp server? For what I understood the general example is this "smtp.domain.com" but my company's domain dont appear in the list, obviously, since the list is so 'small'

Comment: I think you need to contact your email provider for this.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway, at least now I can create accounts!